# Loop textbox and loop input gathering

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I did loop of input tags in a form. My code for this one is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory_tbl";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        echo "<table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product SKU</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Size</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>";
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>" . $row['product_sku'] . "<input type='hidden' name='productsku[]' value='" . $row['product_sku'] . "'></td>
                            <td>" . $row['product_category'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['product_name'] . "</td>
                            <td>" . $row['product_size'] . "</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='productqty[]'></td>
                        </tr>";
                }
        }
```

And this is code when I'm putting the data to database:

```
$event_name = $_POST['eventname'];
$event_date = $_POST['eventdate'];
$event_place = $_POST['eventplace'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];

$product_sku = $_POST['productsku'];
$quantity = $_POST['productqty'];


$sqlcount_product = "SELECT COUNT(product_sku) FROM inventory_tbl WHERE is_deleted = 0;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlcount_product);
$y = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$sqlst = "INSERT INTO stalltransaction_tbl(event_name, event_place, event_date) VALUE ('$event_name', '$event_place', '$event_date');";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlst)) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
}

$x = 0;
while ($x<$y) {
    if (!empty($quantity[$x])) {
        $sqlo = "INSERT INTO stallitems_tbl(stransaction_no, item_no, product_sku, quantity) VALUE ('$last_id', '$x+1', '$product_sku[$x]', '$quantity[$x]');";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sqlo);

        $sqlr = "UPDATE inventory_tbl
        SET no_of_stock = (no_of_stock - '$quantity[$x]'), no_of_avstock = (no_of_avstock - '$quantity[$x]')
        WHERE product_sku = '$product_sku[$x]';";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sqlr);
    }
    $x=$x+1;
}
$x=0;

$sqla = "UPDATE stransaction_tbl
        SET total_amount = (SELECT SUM(I.item_price*O.quantity) FROM order_tbl O JOIN inventory_tbl I ON O.product_sku = I.product_sku WHERE O.transaction_no = '$last_id')
        WHERE transaction_no = '$last_id';";
mysqli_query($conn, $sqla);

$sqlp = "INSERT INTO payment_tbl(transaction_no, payors_name, payment_mode, payment_date, amount) VALUE ('$last_id', '$event_name', 'Cash', '$event_date', '$amount');";
mysqli_query($conn, $sqlp);

header("Location: ../index.php?newstransaction=success");
```

The inputting to database works in stallitems_tbl insert loop. It does the code above but after that loop it stops. I know because the database stransaction and payment hasn't changed. It says like 'Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded'. Help me. Is my code correct? Thanksss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't want to do a complete code review on this question, but I have a sneaking suspicion that it is over-complicated.

As for your:

> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

I reckon you have an infinite loop because `$x` is never stopped by the associative resultset row.

I recommend:

```
$y = mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];
```

...this *should* be a number.

p.s. I'll remove my comments and include my other recommendations:

You should be implementing mysqli prepared statements with placeholders for security reasons.

A `for ($x=0; $x<$y; ++$x) {` loop will be a much cleaner syntax than `$x=0; while($x<$y){...$x=$x+1;}`.

And finally, your script is performing no affected row checking, so `header(...success)` is a bit of an assumption.  `UPDATE` queries can be error-free and still affect zero rows, so you would be wise to include some checkpoints along the way.

Answer (score 0):

your while check in the main loop will never exit.

`$y = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` will contain an array

```
$x = 0;
while ($x<$y) {

}
```

`$x` is an integer, so comparing the 2 will resolve to true. Hence your loop wont ever exit.

**edit**

As mentioned in comments, your result set will contain a count, but will be accessible in an array.  So you need to extract it before you can use it as you are trying to.

However, take note of all the comments.  The code is messy and not well thought out.  Simple housekeeping such as good indenting will help you debug more effectively.

In addition, if you use a good IDE then most of those housekeeping jobs become automatic.  Also consider using [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/), being able to step through the code line by line is an essential tool.

Comment: OP is doing a COUNT(product_sku) in the query so mysqli_num_rows will always return 1.

Comment: Im like so sorry. My prof is an invisible man. Im kinda having hard time learning since Im not guided where to start or whatever. I use brackets. Thank you so much.